# My UITableView cell is not giving me the right information

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, didselectrowatindexpath

I have close to 30 cells being occupied in my UITableView. I used storyboard mode to create the table. When I'm trying to call the cell that I selected its registering as 0 no matter what cell I've chosen. How do I get my cell to register the exact number I pushed and insert that into my currentTag?
Here is what I have so far

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return catNames.count;
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = catNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0x0e/255, green: 0x1b/255, blue: 0x35/255, alpha: 1.0)
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingMiddle
        cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        return cell
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        currentTag = tableView.tag
        println("This is the \(currentTag)")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("table2Segue", sender:self)

    }
```

Comment: Use `currentTag = indexPath.row`. Your `tableView` will always have `tag` as `0` unless you set it to other value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSIndexPath` provides the section and row for the table view selection.

Similarly to how you set the cell's text via `catNames[indexPath.row]`, you should use `indexPath.row` to determine the index of the cell that was tapped.

Therefore:

```
currentTag = indexPath.row;
```

Comment: Ohhh okay! Its nice to know the logic behind that! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `indexPath.row` to find out which cell it is. If you have sections you will need to use `indexPath.section` as well.

Comment: Yes that was it I found out what I was doing wrong to cause a conflict with the indexPath.row. Thanks!!